# Laravel - add to collection from javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

We are making an Information system for a cinema in Laravel. The seats in a room are created by this code:

```
for($row=0;$row<=9;$row++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($col=1;$col<=10;$col++){
        $number = $col+10*$row;
        echo "<td><button onclick='change_state(this)' type='button'>$number</button></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

When the button is clicked, the color changes according to the situation:

```
function change_state(button){
    if (button.style.backgroundColor != "red") {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

We need to get the clicked buttons value to an array in a php code. How could we do that?

Comment: Please please pretty please we are hopeless :(

Comment: Create an comma separated string of clicked number, then add them to the value of input type="hidden", then pass that field to php code through form or ajax.